# Splice function inserting same elements into every index

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension that tracks web requests as you visit websites. Every time the user goes to another website, the extension checks to find the latest entry in the sites array so it knows where in the trackers array to insert the trackers, however for some reason they all copy over to the next element in the trackers array. Here is my code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
if (details.tabId == -1) {
    console.log("Skipping request from inactive tab");
    //return;
}

var notInteresting = Object.keys(activeTabs).every(function(key) {
    if (activeTabs[key] == details.tabId) {

        //Search for correct array index to insert trackers
        outerloop:
        for(i = (currentNum); i--; i < (currentNum-10)){
            //If the element doesn't exist
            if(typeof sites[i] !== 'undefined'){
                curNum = i;
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
        //Check for particular trackers on pages
        var s = details.url;
        console.log("1curNum = " + curNum);

        if(typeof trackers[curNum] === 'undefined'){
            trackers[curNum] = '';
        }

        //Code to identify the trakers based on the URL in webrequests
        if(s.indexOf('doubleclick.net') >= 0){
            console.log("Doubleclick Tracker: ", details.url);
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Doubleclick Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('googleads') >= 0){
            console.log("Google Ads Tracker: ", details.url);
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Google Ads Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('googlesyndication') >= 0){
            console.log("Google Adsense Tracker: ", details.url);
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Google Adsense Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('analytics') >= 0){
            console.log("Analytics Tracker: ", details.url);
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Analytics Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('connect.facebook') >= 0){
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Facebook Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
            console.log("Facebook Tracker: ", details.url);
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('scorecardresearch') >= 0){
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Scorecard Research Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
            console.log("Scorecard Research Tracker: ", details.url);
        }
        else if(s.indexOf('chartbeat') >= 0){
            trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Chartbeat Tracker: </b>"+ s));
            document.getElementById('tracker' + curNum).innerHTML = trackers[curNum];
            console.log("Chartbeat Tracker: ", details.url);
        }
    } else {

    }
});
```

Say I load CNN's website first, I'll get references to "http://z.cdn.turner.com/analytics/cnnexpan/jsmd.min.js", then after about 5 sites, that same link always pops up. I've spent hours trying to figure out why the elements in the previous index get copied over to the new one, but I just can't see the problem. Any advice?

Comment: What the code is basically is doing is re-adding the `trackers[curNum]`? Have you tried to remove that part in the splice function and checked it?

Comment: That piece of code keeps adding the new requests to the same index while the user is on the site. curNum increments when the user goes to another page. When the user is on a page, the extension builds a string of requests by adding to the string each time a new request is found. When the user goes to the next website, curNum increments and the program goes to the next index in the array and starts creating another string of requests.

Comment: So if I remove that line, I will only have the latest tracker URL show up instead of a string of 3 from the same site.

Comment: I think this line : `trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ("<br> <b>Doubleclick Tracker: </b>"+ s));` should be like this `trackers.splice(curNum, 0, ("<br> <b>Doubleclick Tracker: </b>"+ s));` because your code is basically inserting after trackers[curNum] or is it suppose to do that?

Comment: It's supposed to do that as it overwrites the string with a copy of itself + the new request

Comment: One final question, what is the expected output that you want??

Comment: And I think it doesnt overwrite it, it adds right after that position.

Comment: If you want to replace the element, you should use `trackers.splice(curNum, 1, trackers[curNum] + ("...`

Comment: Or better yet: `trackers[curNum] = trackers[curNum] + ("...`

Comment: Changing `trackers.splice(curNum, 0, ...)` to `trackers.splice(curNum, 1, ...)` worked! I also tried`trackers[curNum] = trackers[curNum] + ...` but it didn't work strangely. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem that I can find is with these type of lines:

```
 trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + (...));
```

I think they should be like this:

```
 trackers.splice(curNum+1, 0, (...));
```

Then new tracker get added and you currect tracker will also be there.

Another simple way(Thanks to @rsanchez) to do it would be to simply keep it like this:

```
trackers[curNum] = trackers[curNum] + (...);
```

or

```
trackers.splice(curNum, 1, trackers[curNum] + (...));
```

Comment: @rsanchez the credit goes to you for the second part of the answer.

Comment: Changing `trackers.splice(curNum, 0, trackers[curNum] + ...)` to `trackers.splice(curNum, 1, trackers[curNum] + ...)` worked! I also tried `trackers[curNum] = trackers[curNum] + ...)` but it didn't work strangely. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: `trackers.splice(curNum, 0, (...));` only left me with one tracker in the string

Comment: Now i understood why. Well I edited the answer and I think this solution should also work, i guess. :)